# Get numbers in a matrix in different set positions

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `1x5000` with numbers. Now I am interested in getting values from the matrix in different positions, more precisely in six different places of the matrix. The places should be based on the length, these are the numbers I want to get out:

1. Number in 1/6 of the matrix length
2. Number in 2/6 of the matrix length
3. Number in 3/6 of the matrix length
4. Number in 4/6 of the matrix length
5. Number in 5/6 of the matrix length
6. Number in 6/6 of the matrix length

These values could be printed out in another matrix, so assume the matrix is `1x5000`, 3/6 would give the number in the middle of the matrix. I am new in Matlab and therefore the help is much appreciated!

Comment: 5000 is not divisible by 6

Comment: First off, 5000 is not divisible by 6. Secondly: `x(ceil(linspace(1,5000,6))`.

Comment: @StewieGriffin I know, therefore this have to be solved, just by tanking the next position that is divisible.

Comment: What does "next" mean? Floor? Ceiling? Rounded?

Comment: Lest change it a bit, I want to get the number in exactly 25%, 50%, 75% length of a random (1xLENGTH matrix) matrix.

Comment: What if 25% of the length is not an integer?

Comment: @excaza tanke the next value that is.

Comment: `x((1:3).*numel(x)/4)` if you want the 25, 50, 75% of a matrix that's divisible by 4. If it's not divisible by 4: `x(ceil((1:3).*numel(x)(4))`

Comment: And again, what does "next" mean?

Comment: @excaza is right here. It is important to describe assumptions accruately and precise. next of a float is `val+eps`, which may neither be an integer. A proper explanation may be "If resulting indices are non integer values, I want the indices to be rounded upwards towards the closest integer value.".

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is unclear I can try to give you an example.
First of all you can use [`numel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html) function to get matrix's size.

It's easy to get necessary element in Matlab: you can address directly to any element if you know its number (index). So:
`x(100)` returns 100th element. 
Now you got size and know what to do. Last moment - what to do if `numel(x) / 6` return non integer?

You can use rounding functions: [`ceil`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ceil.html?searchHighlight=ceil), [`floor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/floor.html) or [`round`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html).

```
index = ceil(numel(x)/6) %if you want NEXT element always
result = x(index)
```

Next step: there are a lot of ways to divide data. For example now you have just 6 numbers (1/6, 2/6 and so on) but what if there are 1000 of them? You can't do it manually. So you can use `for` loop, or you can use matrix of indexes or perfect [comment Stewie Griffin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571236/get-numbers-in-a-matrix-in-different-set-positions#comment66452339_39571236).

My example:

```
divider = [6 5 4 3 2 1] % lets take 1/6 1/5 1/4 1/3 1/2 and 1/1
ind = ceil( numel(x)./divider)
res = x(ind)
```

Answer (score 0):

The colon notation in MATLAB provides an easy way to extract a range of elements from v:

```
v(3:7)    %Extract the third through the seventh elements
```

You could either manually input range or use a function to convert fractions into suitable ranges